# c# How to convert list to dictonary by Date field

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a list with 5 item.
Each item contain DateTime field, and another fields.

My objective is to create two chunk, each with their respective dates

In this case, in the list items exist two dates -> 24/11 and 25/11.

I want to create a dictonary by date and each date w'll be contain  item by this date.

Like :
[image]

This is the code:

```
namespace Test
{
public class CostDbDto
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            List<CostDbDto> costList = new List<CostDbDto>();
            costList.Add(new CostDbDto
            {
                Date = DateTime.Parse("2021-11-24 15:03:39"),
                Cost = 3,
                JobId = 111
            });

            costList.Add(new CostDbDto
            {
                Date = DateTime.Parse("2021-11-24 16:03:39"),
                Cost = 55,
                JobId = 111
            });

            costList.Add(new CostDbDto
            {
                Date = DateTime.Parse("2021-11-24 17:03:39"),
                Cost = 22,
                JobId = 111
            });

            costList.Add(new CostDbDto
            {
                Date = DateTime.Parse("2021-11-25 15:03:39"),
                Cost = 44,
                JobId = 111
            });

            costList.Add(new CostDbDto
            {
                Date = DateTime.Parse("2021-11-25 16:03:39"),
                Cost = 33,
                JobId = 111
            });


            var ss = costList.GroupBy(a => a.Date).ToList();


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }



    }
}
```

If you run you we'll get
[image]

I hope that I was clear and thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? Please don't post just images, post actual code.

Comment: You may want to use `LookUp`, `var lookUp = list.ToLookUp(item => item.Key);`

Comment: You are right, I edited and inserted code. I tried your code but don't work for me.. Can you check again?

Comment: But all your datetimes are different, so there are 5 groups of size 1 each. If you don't understand it, think of them as numbers instead: 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 2.5, 2.7. Group by `theNumber` means you get 5 groups, because all the numbers are different. I think you want to `GroupBy(x=>x.Date.Date)` - it is unfortunate that your property is called `Date`, because a DateTime has a property called `Date` too, that removes the time part. If you'd called your `public DateTime Date { get; set; }` as `public DateTime CostDate { get; set; }` then it's less confusingly `GroupBy(x=>x.CostDate.Date)`

Comment: I need only the date, not the time. If you take Date.ToShortDateString(), you will get 25/11/2021. I need two groups by Date

Comment: Re-read my comment; if there is a part you didn't understand, let me know. Don't call your property `Date`; it is confusing, because you hve to call `GroupBy(x=>x.Date.Date)` - the first `Date` is your DateTime property in CostDbDto, the second `Date` is the [`Date` property of a DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-6.0)

Comment: If it's not clear, I would genuinely recommend to rename your `Date` property so it is called `CostDate`, rename your db column too (we should never use reserved words for column names), and then use a code of `GroupBy(x=>x.CostDate.Date)`. Also, don't forget; you've called `ToList()` in your code, but you need to call `ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g=>g.ToList())` after you call groupby.. So in short, the full code would be: `response.GroupBy(x=>x.CostDate.Date).ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.ToList());`. You'll get a `Dictionary<DateTime, List<CostDbDto>>` - the dictionary key dates won't have times

Answer (score 0):

```
list
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(y => y.Value));
```

This should be the main idea behind it.  Obviously, change the variable name to reflect your own code.

Comment: I was added a code example, I tried what you offered, but didn't work for me, can you help me again please

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly convert a list to a dictionary using `.ToDictionary()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0

```
var whateverYouWantToNameYourDictionary = listOfDates.ToDictionary(l => l, l => "Whatever the string is you want. Format it with code however.");
```

Comment: I was added a code example, I tried what you offered, but didn't work for me, can you help me again please